# console.log params but defined

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
export const Data = [
    {
    id:'adkdkdkdk',
    title:'first',
  },
  {
    id:'mvmvmvvm',
    title:'second',
  },
  {
    id:'newoq',
    title:'third',
  },
  {
      id:'dnkdlnsdl',
      title:'four'
  }
  ]
```

this is data

```
const University = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Container>
      <FlatList horizontal data={Data} renderItem={({item})=> (
        <TextContainer onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Stack',{screen:'Information',params:{item}})}>
        <Texts>{item.title}</Texts>
        <Texts>{item.id}</Texts>
      </TextContainer>
      )} keyExtractor={key=>key.id}/>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

and this is code

I want to send params to Information screen, so I used navigation and send params but params is 'undefined' when console.log... what is problem?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Where is your console.log ?

Comment: As for the problem, you need to put quotes around your attribute values.

Answer (score 2):

here is a working code:

```
     const data = [ 
     {
    id:'adkdkdkdk',
    title:'first',
  },
  {
    id:'mvmvmvvm',
    title:'second',
  },
  {
    id:'newoq',
    title:'third',
  },
  {
      id:'dnkdlnsdl',
      title:'four'
  }
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList      
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <>
                    <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                    </>
                )}
            />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just saw that FlatList returns `item`, this seems about right